# Should a new process created in a Java program be destroyed after use?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, process

I'm creating a process using the Process Builder and do a waitFor() to suspend the current thread till the process completes. 
Should I do a process.destroy() in a finally block after the process has executed, to ensure the process resources can be reclaimed? Or close the streams associated with the process  at the very least? Would that be necessary even after waitFor()?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html)

> Running processes hold resources. When a process is no longer used, the process should be closed by calling destroy(). This will kill the process and release the resources that it holds.

So yes in general circumstances if you create a process you need to call `destroy()` in finally block.
Also note `destroy()` will also release JVM resources hold by the process which includes the streams.

If you are using `waitFor ()` then it causes the calling thread to wait for the native process associated with this object to finish executing. This should close the process and cleanup the resources for normal process termination. However if it is abnormal process termination (You can know that by the return value of waitFor() method) you will have to cleanup resources.

Also calling `destroy()` on a Process already destroyed causes no harm.

Comment: Is destroy() method kills the process normally ? As I get the status of '1'by process.exitValue() after process.destro().

Comment: How We can close process normally with status/exitValue of 0 ?